# bindService restrict client to specific app

Tags: android, service

I need a way to restrict use of a service to a specific app. That is, I have an app containing a service, which the user can install, and a companion app. I want only the companion app to be able to use the service. I invoke the service with `bindIntent`.

I've been looking to see if the client's package is part of the intent passed to `onBind`, but don't see it. In the service, is there a way to obtain the client's package?

Are there any other ways to identify a client app that can't be spoofed? Is there something I can put in the manifest for the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element) element in the `Manifest.xml` can be used to control that:

```
<service
    ...
    android:exported="false" />
```

> Whether or not components of other applications can invoke the `service` or interact with it — `true` if they can, and `false` if not. When the value is `false`, only components of the same application or applications with the same user ID can start the `service` or bind to it.

Comment: I need exactly one "external" app to work with the service. I believe setting exported to false will prevent that. I modified my O.P. to be more clear.

Comment: @PeriHartman this can be accomplished by adding a custom `permission` element with `protectionLevel="signature"` and also requiring that `permission` for the `service`. this works at least while both packages were signed off with the same key; signing v2 might not use the same keys, because upload keys != release keys.

Comment: I just took a quick look at the documentation. If I understand it, I think it will work. Will do some experiments.

Comment: This does, indeed, seem to work. I created a new keystore and built the client app with that. Even with a matching "sharedUserId", it failed to bind with the service. Then, using the proper keystore *and* matching "sharedUserId", the client worked. Thanks !!!